# Создание массива разных объектов

Tags: java

Есть два интерфейса

```
public interface Creep {
    void creep();
}  
public interface Wriggle extends Creep {
    void wriggle();
}
```

И 3 класса

```
public class Creature {
    public void whoAmI(){
        System.out.print("I'am Creature -");
    }
}
public class Dog extends Creature implements Creep {
    @Override
    public void creep(){
        System.out.println("Creep from Dog");
    };
}
public class Snake extends Creature implements Wriggle {
    public void wriggle(){
        System.out.println("wriggle from Snake");
    }
    public void creep(){
        System.out.println("creep from Snake");
    }
}
```

Хочу создать массив состоящий из классов Dog, Snake. Как это правильно реализовать? Сделал следующее:

```
List<Creep> list = new ArrayList<Creep>();
list.add(new Snake());
list.add(new Dog());
list.get(0).creep();
list.get(0).wriggle();
```

Но на вызове wriggle() получаю ошибку компиляции, что этого метода нет, как тогда можно реализовать массив для этих объектов?

Comment: Стоит уточнить `получаю ошибку компиляции.` т.к. ошибок компиляции +100500. Но я и так могу сказать в чем проблема тип элементов в списке Creep. Вызываете вы метод wriggle. А он появляется у интерфейса Wriggle, который наследуется от Creep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в Generic. Так как вы указали `List<Creep> list` с типом `Creep`, то у вас `get` и вернул `Creep`. (Это возможно за счет того, что в Java можно делать так: `Creep c = new Snake();`)

На самом деле внутри листа будет лежать просто `Object`, а тип который вы указываете в `<>` доступен лишь во время компиляции.

Если вы хотите получить объект правильного типа, нужно сделать так:

```
((Snake) list.get(0)).wriggle();
```

Но учтите, что восходящие преобразования - это плохо и их по возможности следует избегать.